# What the differences between node ports and what is best to choose?

Tags: node.js, port

One tutorial uses port 3000. Other uses 8080 while someone just uses 8000 or other ports.

What all of those mean and why should I use 3000 instead of 8080 or vice versa?

Thanks.

Comment: 8080 port is faster

Comment: @LevKuznetsov is joking (I hope)

Comment: You are asking a question like: some tutorials use "myDatabase" as their database name, others use "database". Which should I use? There is no better option if you know what are you doing, read about it.

Comment: I am just asking if there differences between ports or they just some random  names like "dbName".. maybe is there a reference of ports with their meanings?

Comment: There are some rules that you must have, but yes, they are "random", you can use a port like 58913 if you want. Only take care with the range (from 0 to 65535), and don't use an already used port. Read some info about it if you want to know more about that.

Comment: So what you say is: there is a range of allowed ports. I can choose any of what I want in order to server my node project for example, but I have to verify that I am not overlap another popular port, because one port cannot serve for two services. So there some agreed ports like 443 is SSL, I should not use it for my own projects, right?

Comment: You can use ports like 443. It is common when you deploy to production use standard ports in order to access your web page (or other services) without write explicitily the port. If you web page is on port 3000, you should execute on your browser something like `http://myapp.com:3000`, but if you use the port 80, you don't need to write it, because it is used automatically by the browser.

Comment: Okay. and 443 is SSL that means that when I am accessting https :// myapp.com is like to access: http://myapp.com:443?

Comment: 443 is HTTPS, not SSL. And it will be used by default by your browsers, so you don't need to write it. You can access an application listening on port 443 using either `https://myapp.com` or `https://myapp.com:443`. For the browser will be the same.

Comment: Okay thank you for the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ports are only endpoints for communicate one application with another.
There are some ports uses by default depending of the protocol, for example 80 for HTTP.

There is no restriction with it, you can use the HTTP protocol over port 443 if you want, but some applications (like web browsers) use default port numbers if you don't explicitily set another one.

The number of available ports are from 0 to 65535, there are some conventions but you can use anyone you want.

Ports like 3000 or 8080 are typical values when you are developing an application (it is not a rule, but a convention).